# (Using $this when not in object context) when use extend

Tags: php

The problem is, even though the class is being extended php tells me that I not using in the correct context, any solution or explanation?

My code:

```
<?php

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public $name = 'main';

    public function index($name)
    {
        $this->set('name', $name);
        $this->renderPartial('main');
    }
}
```

The error is

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/wikizweb/www/wikizcms/admin/protected/controllers/MainController.php on line 9

Comment: Can you show the code you're running that throws the error?

Comment: I see the class, but neither its instantiation or usage.

Comment: There is an autoload charging these classes, and a router class calls all of them through user requests

Comment: More info would be helpful, eh?  What is your exact error message?  What does the `Controller` class look like?

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/wikizweb/www/wikizcms/admin/protected/controllers/MainController.php on line 9

Comment: You're missing something. Are you sure that the definition for Control exists when when the object is instantiated?

Answer (score 3):

So your problem is this

> Using $this when not in object context

Or, to put it another way, you're not instantiating the class first. You need to do something like this

```
$class = new MainController(); // class instance, with $this
$class->index('Name');
```

Comment: Don't know why this is down voted when it is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The function in your controller:

```
public function index($name)
```

Assumes that you are sending the parameter 'name' with the request.  Depending on what framework you are using and how you set the routing, the name may be part of the url.  Please add the url route that you are trying to match and the actual error you are getting.

And your variable is public.  Try:

```
$this->name = $name;
```

And see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but trouble seems is the instantiation of the Controller class, for that when I instantiate using a variable it works normally, but when the use through extends happens this error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, and the next note describes more or less what is the problem:

> Please note, that when calling call_user_func_array() to redirect
>   parameters between inherited classes, you should not use $this,
>   because $this always refers to the class which has been instantiated.
>   The following code even seems to crash PHP (PHP does not report error
>   but the process simply terminates), because the the parameters are
>   redirected only one level up (to class foo_bar2):
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

I'm using that function to call the behavior of my application, but i can't use $this, it's looks like static methods, and i solved this problem instantiating, And to solve this problem I instantiate the class before calling the function `call_user_func_array()`